# Explicit solution of system of second order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there explicit solution to system
$$
\ddot{\varepsilon}_n(t)+\sum_{k=1}^N\gamma_k^n\dot{\varepsilon}_k(t)+\alpha_n\varepsilon_n(t)=f_n(t),~~ t>0,
$$
$$
\varepsilon_n(0)=w_n,~~ \dot{\varepsilon_n}(0)=w_n^1,
$$
$n=1,2,3,...,N$, in which $\gamma_k^n=const$, $0<\alpha_n=const$, $w_n, w_n^1=const$, $f_n$ are bounded, continuously differentiable functions.

Comment: Why don't you write it as a first order system?

Comment: I don`t think that converting it into
$$
\dot{\varepsilon}_n=\mu_n,~~ \dot{\mu}_n=-\sum_{k=1}^N\gamma_k^n\mu_k-\alpha_n\varepsilon_n+f_n,
$$
simplifies the solution, does it?

Comment: Sure it does! Now you can write as $\dot{x} = A x + f(t)$ and use all you knowledge on _linear systems with constant coefficients_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us introduce
$$ \dot{\varepsilon}_n=\mu_n,~~ \dot{\mu}_n=-\sum_{k=1}^N\gamma_k^n\mu_k-\alpha_n\varepsilon_n+f_n.$$
Then, the general solution will be
$$
\nu(t)=\exp\left[\mathcal{A}t\right]\nu(0)+\int_0^t\exp\left[\mathcal{A}(t-\tau)\right]f(\tau)d\tau,
$$
in which $\nu=\left(\varepsilon_1~~ \varepsilon_2~~...~~\varepsilon_N~~ \mu_1~~ \mu_2~~...~~ \mu_N\right)^T$, $\nu(0)=\left(w_1~~ w_2~~...~~w_N~~ w_1^1~~ w_2^1~~...~~ w_N^1\right)^T$, $f=\left(0~~ 0~~...~~0~~ f_1~~ f_2~~...~~ f_N\right)^T$,
$$
\mathcal{A}=\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \dots & & & & & & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \\
-\alpha_1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -\gamma_1^1 & -\gamma_2^1 & \dots & -\gamma_N^1 \\
0 & -\alpha_2 & \dots & 0 & -\gamma_1^2 & -\gamma_2^2 & \dots & -\gamma_N^2 \\
\vdots & \dots & & & & & & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & -\alpha_N & -\gamma_1^N & -\gamma_2^N & \dots & -\gamma_N^N \\
\end{vmatrix}.
$$